# Put minimum price order condition on single product in store

Tags: php, opencart

I have my shopping website in opencart and i want  to put certain conditions on particular products in my store.
For example: I have a product in my store and i want to put following order condition on it.

Conditions: You need to order at least $50.00 in products to be able to to purchase this

Could you please tell me which is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no default method for that, AFAIK. You have to write a simple VQMod, which will check order subtotal upon add to cart operation.